Get javascript variable's value in Django url template tag, but the following error pops up
In my django app, when i change the car in my car choice in the form, this error pops up: [15/Apr/2024 15:16:49] "GET /unavailable-dates/10/?start_date=2024-01-01&end_date=2024-12-31 HTTP/1.1" 404 2932
urls.py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # Other URL patterns
    path('unavailable-dates/<int:car_id>/', views.get_unavailable_dates, name='unavailable_dates'),
]

booking_form.html
<!-- Inline JavaScript -->
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#id_car').change(function(){  
                var carId = $(this).val();  // Get selected car ID
                
                // Make an AJAX request to fetch unavailable dates for the selected car
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/unavailable-dates/' + carId + '/',  // URL of the get_unavailable_dates view
                    data: {
                        'start_date': '2024-01-01',  // Example start date, replace with actual value
                        'end_date': '2024-12-31'      // Example end date, replace with actual value
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        // Handle the response data here
                        console.log("Unavailable dates:", data);
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.error("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

views.py
def get_unavailable_dates(request, car_id):
    try:
        car = Car.objects.get(id=car_id)
    except Car.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse("Car not found.", status=404)

    start_date_str = request.GET.get('start_date')
    end_date_str = request.GET.get('end_date')

    if not start_date_str or not end_date_str:
        return HttpResponse("Start date and end date must be provided in the request.", status=400)

    try:
        start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date_str, '%Y-%m-%d')
        end_date = datetime.strptime(end_date_str, '%Y-%m-%d')
    except ValueError:
        return HttpResponse("Invalid date format. Dates must be in YYYY-MM-DD format.", status=400)

    # Fetch unavailable dates directly from the database
    unavailable_dates = Booking.objects.filter(car=car, period_end__gte=start_date, period_start__lte=end_date).values_list('period_start', 'period_end')

    # Create a list of unavailable dates based on booking periods
    unavailable_dates_list = []
    for booking_start, booking_end in unavailable_dates:
        current_date = booking_start
        while current_date <= booking_end:
            unavailable_dates_list.append(current_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
            current_date += timedelta(days=1)

    # Return unavailable dates as plain text
    response_content = "\n".join(unavailable_dates_list)
    return HttpResponse(response_content, content_type="text/plain")

I tried to Get javascript variable's value in Django url template tag but it was not working and the same error always pops up

Do you actually have any Car objects in the database with the id 10? You're getting a 404 error which corresponds to the return inside your first try-except block.
